# Compare two files and adding zero if no values in 2nd file

Tags: linux, shell, unix, awk

I have two text files `zero.txt` and `value.txt`.

zero.txt:

```
hour Value1  value2  
0        0       0
1        0       0
2        0       0
3        0       0
4        0       0
```

upto 24.

and value.txt:

```
hour Value1  value2  
0        1       1
2        2       2
4        3       4
```

I want to compare 1st column in both the files (actually the first column is hour 0-24). If the `values.txt` has the hour value I need to print that row in `output.txt` if no values I need print hour with zeros in `output.txt`. like below:

and `output.txt`:

```
hour Value1  value2  
0        1       1
1        0       0
2        2       2
3        0       0
4        3       4
```

How to achieve this Unix?

Comment: I assume the two files are sorted on the first column.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is what you want:

```
$ awk 'NR==FNR{a[$1]=$0;next}($1 in a){print a[$1];next}{print $0}' value zero
hour Value1  value2
0        1       1
1        0       0
2        2       2
3        0       0
4        3       4
```

**Explanation:**

The structure of `awk` scripts are a series of conditionals and blocks in the form `conditional{block}`. The script is executed per record that is read in the input and if the conditional is evaluated as true the code in the block will be executed. A simple example is `awk '/hour/{print $0}' value` where the input is the file `value` and the script `/hour/{print $0}` executed on every line in the file. The conditional here is a regexp match for the string `hour` since only the first line in the files matches it will be the only line printed in the output.

- `NR` is a special `awk` variable that is incremented for every record read. By default records are split on new lines in `awk`. `FNR` is almost the same but is reset everytime a new file is read. So the condition `NR==FNR` is only true when we are reading the first file `value`.
- `a[$1]=$0` is creating a line look-up using the first field as the key.
- `next` grabs the next line in file skipping the following blocks.
- When the second file is being read we check if the first field if the look-up we created from the first file `($1 in a)` if it is we print that value and get the next line.
- If the first field isn't a key in the array we print the line in the file we are looking at `zero`.

Using some `awk` [idiums](http://backreference.org/2010/02/10/idiomatic-awk/) we can shorten the script but it's probably best to be verbose whilst starting out:

```
awk 'NR==FNR{a[$1]=$0;next}$1 in a{$0=a[$1]}1' value zero
```

You should really start by reading [Effective awk programming](http://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.pdf).

Comment: Thanks for you reply, can you please explain the syntax.

Comment: Second block can be shortened to `$1 in a{$0=a[$1]}1`

Comment: @GanzRicanz I have added an explanation and pointed you too two great references. Don't forgot to upvote all answers that you found helpful and accept the most helpful answer by clicking the tick mark next to it.

Answer (score 4):

You can make use of `join` command.

```
join -o 1.1,2.2,2.3 -a 1 -e 0 zero.txt value.txt
```

Comment: This is the best answer, much better than mine.

Answer (score 1):

One solution using [vim](/questions/tagged/vim)

Content of `script.vim`:

```
set backup
buffer 2
2,$ yank 
buffer 1
2 put!
2,$ ! sort -sun -k1,1
saveas! output.txt
qa!
```

Run it like:

```
vim -u NONE -N -S script.vim zero.txt value.txt
```

And will create a file named `output.txt` with content:

```
hour Value1  value2  
0        1       1
1        0       0
2        2       2
3        0       0
4        3       4
```

How does it work? It copies the content of `values.txt`, pastes all it just after the header of `zero.txt` and later sorts it by first column deleting duplicates.

Answer (score -2):

If we ignore the header and use bash script (you will need to adjust the margins):

```
while read x1 x2 x3
do
    if grep -q "^$x1\>" value.txt
    then
        grep "^$x1\>" value.txt >> output.txt
    else
        echo "$x1      $x2       $x3" >> output.txt
    fi
done < zero.txt
```

Comment: This won't work as hour `1` will match hour `11`,`12`,`13` ect same for hour `2`. Easily fixed with a space or the `-w` option but regardless of that isn't a good solution for the problem.

Comment: Clumsy solution. You are scanning the `value.txt` a lot of times.

Comment: Fixed the end of word issue.  Multiple scanninf of value.txt can be fixed by reading in the values and comparing those, assuming that both files are sorted.